# Why is Google Chrome trying to run netbiosd attempting to connect to 192.168.2.255?

Tags: macos, network, google-chrome, firewall

I usually don't use Google Chrome, because on my MacBook I'm addicted to Safari.

Today when I launched Chrome, it ran netbiosd to connect to the local IP: *192.168.2.255*. The local IP does not exist on the network and my local subnet is different than it is attempting to connect. I use a software called [LuLu](https://objective-see.com/products/lulu.html) to detect outgoing calls. It is a packet filter similar to Little Snitch.

So where did it come from? What is netbiosd process?

Answer (score 1):

Netbios searches for local services like shared files and printers. What device is at 192.168.2.255 and did you enable chrome to try to print or open files?

This could be harmless or it could be code running that you don’t want to.

The process is a helper, Apple installed it, it’s running code that google likely was told by you to run.

Comment: `*.*.*.255` is the default broadcast address for almost any small router. It is your broadcast address, then it’s talking to “the room” and not to a device. Netbiosd as some other daemons/agent/services often use the broadcast address to detect services/devices/hosts! It's a like a *Hello all...!*; *Hello Donald, here Iowa!*; *Hello Donald, here Florida!* etc.

Comment: @klanomath Yeah - I should have asked for the netmask  - almost always 192.168.x.y it would be broadcast - good call

Comment: Just a guess: Chromecast-related

Comment: @bmike no the connection does not ceases, however if i do not allow netbiosd, chrome doesnt have internet access.

Comment: @klanomath: 255 ending is not a valid proof that it’s broadcast, it’s actually a mistake to tell so *w/o knowing the netmask*

Comment: @poige I know (and later I wanted to add *probably* but was too late). But in a home network I've never seen a 192.168.2.0/23 (or smaller) network....

Comment: In fact /24 is a smaller network than than /23, and it’s (/24) is most often used size in SOHO. (Not really a nitpicking but clarification rather).

Comment: @klanomath I’ve made that edit for you